# split the lines which have words separated by more than one white space

Tags: java, regex, split

I am parsing some text files line by line, my need is to split the lines which have words separated by more than one white space. please suggest me how to do this

sample text

```
John     is      working  in London
```

required output

```
John 
is 
working
in London
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\s{2,}` to match multiple spaces:

```
String text = "John     is      working  in London";
String[] words = text.split("\\s{2,}");
for (String word : words)
    System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. `\1+` will replace one or more white spaces.

```
 String str="John     is      working  in London";
       String[] arr=str.replaceAll("([\" \"])\\1+"," ").split(" ");
       for(String i:arr){
           System.out.println(i.trim());
       }
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/Vvpodq)

Out put

```
John
is
working
in
London
```

Comment: Would this work for words seperated by a tab and a space?

Comment: @Qwerky yes. you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple regex:

```
String[] words = str.split("  +");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java.util.StringTokenizer class.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("John     is      working  in London"," ",false);
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println("StringTokenizer Output: " + st.nextElement());
    }
```

Output:

```
John
is
working
in
London
```